# Django: dynamically sharing static files

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project in django 1.4.4, what i am trying to achieve is i have website's index pages mapped with a unique url in database. whenever url hits that url, it should load that website.

I am able to load the index.html(easy) using http://lclhst.com/landing/one-bush

But the problem is the static files that web page auto loads.

so what i have right now is (website) in media/uploads/{unique-no}/index.html and other media files. I tried to make an all url accepting view but i think django auto-tries to serve media files when requested so all the hits like [http://lclhst.com/landing/one-bush/_include/images/dot.jpg](http://localhost.com/landing/one-bush/_include/images/dot.jpg) are being 404'd.

i am looking for any mistake in my approach or some better approach.